# Magento redirecting to old URL after duplicating site

Tags: magento, redirect

I'm struggling with a Magento multi store install. The old setup was one Magento install with two sites / stores all pointing to the same folder. Now the client wants 2 independent websites so changes to one won't mess the other.

Anyway, the database was duplicated, the files were copied, var/cache, var/session, var/tmp were emptied. I've changed the database params in app/etc/local.xml, the .htaccess file doesn't have any hard coded rules.

The problem is that sitea.com keeps redirecting to siteb.com and the admin area is not working, so I have to do everything in the console or phpMyAdmin.

What are the database tables where I have to do the changes ? What am I missing ?

Answer (score 20):

The base_url in the core_config_data did the trick, combined with deleting everything in var/cache, var/session, var/tmp, and the system /tmp folder

Comment: Actually, the deletion of the contents of those folders isn't really required/necessary as they are not related with routing and request handling. Let's say it's more like a placebo or something.

Comment: It is necessary if config file is cached

Comment: Please do not create a new answer to say that someone else's answer was correct. Instead, up-vote and mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

On sitea.com, you might want to take a look at its database and the `core_config_data` table for the base URL. OR, you could try and execute the following query:

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value`='http://sitea.com/' WHERE `value` LIKE 'http://%' LIMIT 2;
```

do the same on siteb.com's database for good measure

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value`='http://siteb.com/' WHERE `value` LIKE 'http://%' LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: @seth-jeremy-malaki Thanks ! In the core_config_data table I changed web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url to http://www.sitea.com/ and now the redirect is gone, but all the links to the .js files are broken, looking like : http://www.sitea.com/home/sitea/public_html/js/prototype/prototype.js . Any ideas on this one ?

Comment: I changed the permissions on the media/js folder and now it works !

Comment: Also you have to make sure you include the trailing / in the URLs. Doesn't work without it.

Comment: Also make sure your permissions aren't too much (e.g. 777). Make it so that it is just enough for the web server to have read and write access to it.

Answer (score 0):

When updating the configuration in the backend of Magento for the the transfer of a production website be cautious of editing the base URL information in the Configuration panel. Once these values change the site will no longer be accessible.

We prefer to transfer the site and then make these changes to the database in the core_config_data table.

If you get locked out of the backend, update database, remove var/cache directory and see if that's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem 
try what i did :

**Step 1:**

romove cache with **SSH** :

```
rm -rf /var/tmp/magento/*
```

**Step 2:**

**PS:** In order to use the Magento Connect Manager you may have to reset the PEAR configuration settings. To do this, simply remove the file `downloader/pearlib/pear.ini`, and a new one will be created automatically.

**Step 3:**

**RESET FILE PERMISSIONS**

To make sure that all javascript files, CSS, and images load correctly, you should reset the file permissions to the recommended settings for your new server.

Run the following commands from your Magento root directory (e.g. public_html):

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this issue over and over again.
I know it has nothing to do with the cache, and is simply a DB issue since I can change the DB name in env, and it breaks.

Now, I followed the instructions that Seth made earlier (finding and changing the DB values) and it worked, partially.  I'm not sure I used his code exactly, but there were 3 rows I needed to change:

- web/unsecure/base_url
- web/secure/base_url
- web/unsecure/base_link_url

Changing those 3 in the core_config_data table did the trick.